# How to grep rows that have value less than or equal to value

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, grep

```
size=139
size=9292
size=140
size=139
size=139
size=10213
size=139
size=140
size=11186
size=139
size=139
size=140
size=12342
size=139
size=139
size=140
size=11360
```

How can I grep rows that has greater value than 1000 from size.txt ?

Also, is there any way that I could find this information from entire folder, which has many txt files like this  ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk -F= '$2 > 1000' filename
```

This can be used with many file names:

```
awk -F= '$2 > 1000' *
```

Or combined with `find` to do it to subfolders as well:

```
find directory -type f -exec awk -F= '$2 > 1000' '{}' \;
```

For the latter two, it may be desirable to print the file name as well as the actual result (mimicking the behavior of `grep`), which could be achieved like this:

```
awk -F= '$2 > 1000 { print FILENAME ": " $0 }' *
```

Answer (score 2):

With bash builin commands:

```
while IFS="=" read variable value; do
  [[ $value -gt 1000 ]] && echo "${variable}=${value}"
done < file
```

Output:

```
size=9292
size=10213
size=11186
size=12342
size=11360
```

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep "size=[0-9]{4}" size.txt
```

Comment: This would match `size=0001`

Comment: egrep "[1-9][0-9]{3}" | grep -v "=1000$"